# sending out rf signals to an android for something like a rasperrypi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to send out a signal from a Raspberry Pi which opens an app on an android device when in range? (~1-2 meters, depending on the transmitter I'll use).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). Use of Bluetooth Near would be your best bet, given the the proximity desired. Still, you may need to put the raspberry pi in a cardboard box to get the bluetooth signal down enough to get near the 1-2m you want. When tasker sees the pi's bluetooth, you can configure it to open the app.

Comment: i know bluetooth is optimal but i dont think bluetooth is an option , i want the app to be always in the background waiting for the trigger signal to activate the app ,

Comment: You could do the same with wi-fi, but the range will be far greater. Why do you say bluetooth is not an option?

Comment: wifi or bluetooth are dependent on me activating them or leaving them active  thats why i dont think its a valid option

Comment: And the other option is to what... plug some type of radio into your phone? I'd say use RFID if your phone has it, but that is additional hardware for the raspberry pi and isn't going to work at 1-2 m. If you use what is already there in the form of bluetooth, the tasker option seems to be the best bet.

Comment: hmmmmmm the idea is not to add any hardware to the phone , its okay to add hardware to the pi though , btw how does tasker (BT near) work exactly  does it always check for available BT devices ? because if so that would be ideal :)

Comment: Yes, Using Tasker's BT Near will allow you to assign an action when a bluetooth signal is in range. Just select the BT from the Pi -- super easy.

Comment: ill try it out also is tasker open-source because i  want to embed it to the os , i have a fully functioning nexus 4 running 7,1 nougat to experiment on